# Agda mode in Aquamacs

Tags: emacs, agda, aquamacs, agda-mode

I can't get agda mode to work on Aquamacs. I am running macOS Sierra. Agda version 2.5.4 and Aquamacs 3.3

Here is what I get when I run the agda-mode commands

```
agda-mode setup
It seems as if setup has already been performed.


agda-mode locate 
/usr/local/Cellar/agda/2.5.4/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.4.3/Agda-2.5.4/emacs-mode/agda2.el

agda-mode compile 
Symbol's function definition is void: byte-compile-disable-warning
Symbol's function definition is void: byte-compile-disable-warning
Symbol's function definition is void: byte-compile-disable-warning
Symbol's function definition is void: byte-compile-disable-warning
Symbol's function definition is void: byte-compile-disable-warning
Symbol's function definition is void: byte-compile-disable-warning
Symbol's function definition is void: byte-compile-disable-warning
Symbol's function definition is void: byte-compile-disable-warning
Unable to compile the following Emacs Lisp files:
/usr/local/Cellar/agda/2.5.4/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.4.3/Agda-2.5.4/emacs-mode/agda2-abbrevs.el
/usr/local/Cellar/agda/2.5.4/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.4.3/Agda-2.5.4/emacs-mode/annotation.el
/usr/local/Cellar/agda/2.5.4/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.4.3/Agda-2.5.4/emacs-mode/agda2-queue.el
/usr/local/Cellar/agda/2.5.4/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.4.3/Agda-2.5.4/emacs-mode/eri.el
/usr/local/Cellar/agda/2.5.4/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.4.3/Agda-2.5.4/emacs-mode/agda2.el
/usr/local/Cellar/agda/2.5.4/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.4.3/Agda-2.5.4/emacs-mode/agda-input.el
/usr/local/Cellar/agda/2.5.4/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.4.3/Agda-2.5.4/emacs-mode/agda2-highlight.el
/usr/local/Cellar/agda/2.5.4/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.4.3/Agda-2.5.4/emacs-mode/agda2-mode.el
```

And of course when I open Aquamacs, I get this error:

> File error: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, /bin/bash: agda-mode: command not found

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the following three lines to my .bash_profile

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin/agda-mode:$PATH`
`export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/agda/2.5.4/bin/agda-mode:$PATH`
`export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/agda/2.5.4/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.4.3/Agda-2.5.4/emacs-mode/:$PATH`